# Using window.location.href.replace + click through for button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My button isn't working, my current url is being added to the click through url I'm specifying and adding it to my button.

```
window.location.href.replace('://m','://www') + "/olat/workflows/olat-main/getting-started.aspx"
```

Is adding "www.Site/mysite/page1/olat/workflows/olat-main/getting-started.aspx" into my button.

Comment: where's the rest of the code and the HTML for your button and a description of what you expect this to actually *do*?

Comment: The `+` operator **returns** the concatenated string, it doesn't modify the left argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the concatenation back to `window.location`:

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace('://m','://www') + "/olat/workflows/olat-main/getting-started.aspx";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by using

```
window.location.origin.replace('://m','://www') + "/olat/workflows/olat-main/getting-started.aspx"
```